# Multimap in Processing

Tags: java, hashmap, processing, multimap

I would like to know a way to use multimap in Processing IDE.

Is there any libraries which I can use?

I need to add several values for same key in a map.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add following library

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

```
Multimap<String,Object> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

public class MutliMapTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
  Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

  // Adding some key/value
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
  myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

  // Getting the size
  int size = myMultimap.size();
  System.out.println(size);  // 4

  // Getting values
  Collection<String> fruits = myMultimap.get("Fruits");
  System.out.println(fruits); // [Bannana, Apple, Pear]

  Collection<String> vegetables = myMultimap.get("Vegetables");
  System.out.println(vegetables); // [Carrot]

  // Iterating over entire Mutlimap
  for(String value : myMultimap.values()) {
   System.out.println(value);
  }

  // Removing a single value
  myMultimap.remove("Fruits","Pear");
  System.out.println(myMultimap.get("Fruits")); // [Bannana, Pear]

  // Remove all values for a key
  myMultimap.removeAll("Fruits");
  System.out.println(myMultimap.get("Fruits")); // [] (Empty Collection!)
 }
}
```

You can download from here

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: Thank you, How can I import this library in processing IDE?

Comment: If you r using `Eclipse` then add in your project `lib` folder for `Processing IDE` i don't have any knowledge.

Comment: That download link only has some PDF files. Isn't it? Shouldn't there be any jar files? adding libs in Processing IDE is as same as in Eclipse.

Comment: I downloaded the jar file and now the Collection type does not get identified by Processing

Comment: `Multimap` identify ? Now ur problem `Collection` not identify?  `Collection` is Part of Java you have to import `java.util.Collection`

Comment: Hey, did exactly as you said. Now it works like a charm. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

Multimap seems to be a part of the Apache commons collections library. Download the zip file that contains it from [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi) (commons-collections4-4.0-bin.zip) unzip it and take the jar file (commons-collections4-4.0.jar) from there. You then have to create a folder in your sketch folder called "code" and put the jar in there...!

Here's an example how to use it in Processing:

```
import java.util.Collection;

void setup() {
 MultiMap mhm = new MultiValueMap();
 mhm.put("Fruit", "Apple");
 mhm.put("Fruit", "Banana");
 mhm.put("Fruit", "Kiwi");
 Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get("Fruit");
 for(Object o: coll) {
   println(o);
 }
}
```

...or, you don't need the import if you know that you will only put Strings as values:

```
void setup() {
 MultiMap mhm = new MultiValueMap();
 mhm.put("Fruit", "Apple");
 mhm.put("Fruit", "Banana");
 mhm.put("Fruit", "Kiwi");
 ArrayList<String> coll = (ArrayList<String>) mhm.get("Fruit");
 for(String o: coll) {
   println(o);
 }
}
```

...or, just roll your own! Like this:

```
// This essentially says that you want to create a map 
// with keys of type String and values of type List of String
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

// add a new ArrayList of Strings in the map:
myMap.put("Fruits",new ArrayList<String>());

// add Strings in the list:
myMap.get("Fruits").add("Apple");
myMap.get("Fruits").add("Banana");
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please elaborate this by an example?

Comment: @Hasala yep, there you go

Comment: Thanks Petros. Your help is much appreciated.